# Vibrations after polarization of light

Tags: optics

When we polarize a light, do we get electric vibrations, magnetic vibrations or the mixture of both.

If both, then how can both electric and magnetic vibrations occur in single plane because polarization actually means to confine these vibrations into one plane?

Answer (score 1):

The plane of polarization refers to the plane in which the electric field oscillates. The magnetic field oscillates perpendicular to the electric field, and also perpendicular to the direction of propagation (assuming we are talking about a plane wave here.)

Comment: doesn't a polarized light has a single type of vibration in one direction?

Comment: In a plane wave, the electric and magnetic fields always both oscillate, and they always both oscillate perpendicular to each other.

Comment: how can they oscillate in a single plane if they are perpendicular to each other?

Comment: They don't oscillate in a single plane. The electric field oscillates in a plane, and the magnetic field oscillates in a plane perpendicular to the electric field. The plane of polarized light refers to the plane in which the electric field oscillates, _not_ the magnetic field.